# In R, how do I randomly select (and average) groups of 3 and (and the remaining 2) variables among 5?

Tags: r, dataframe, random

I have 400 rows that have a bunch of columns, with the last five being: a,b,c,d,e

For each row, I want to randomly select three of the above 5 variables and do rowmeans(varx,vary,varz) to make column trio_average, and the other two making pair_average.

For example, one row might be the mean of b,d,e for column "trio_average" and the mean of a,c for "pair_average", and the next might be the mean of a,c,e and b,d.

I did this in a pretty roundabout way...I used "randomizr()" to generate a variable called "trio_set" with 400 random (conditional random to keep them all equal) trios of the 5 variables. There's 10 possible combinations of the 5 variables so I have 40 each of for example "a_c_e", "b_c_d" etc.

Then, I used a series of 10 if_else statements:

```
data <- transform(data, trio_average = ifelse(trio_set = "a_b_c", rowMeans(data[c("a","b","c")]),
    ifelse(trio_set = "a_b_d", rowMeans(data[c("a","b","d")]), ....
```

I would then do this another 10 times for the pairs.

This does get the job done but in reality, my column names are much longer than e.g. "a" so my code in the end is pretty bad looking and inefficient. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I would reshape my table long (e.g. with `data.table::melt`), so that you're selecting 3 _rows_ at random (by group) instead of 3 _columns_-per-row (which is a bit more unwieldy). It would be easier to flesh out the details on this if you could provide a minimal dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using base R, we can use row-wise `apply`

```
cols <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
df$trio_average <- apply(df[cols], 1, function(x) mean(sample(x, 3), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Select the specific columns you are interested in and for each row randomly select 3 values and take their `mean`.

---

To get the `mean` of the numbers which were not selected we can store the index of random numbers and use it to get two pairs of mean for each row.

```
df[c('chosen', 'remaining')] <- t(apply(df[cols], 1, function(x) {
      inds <- sample(seq_along(x), 3)
      c(mean(x[inds]), mean(x[-inds]))
}))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this elegant solution, however I failed to include a very important detail, which is that I also have to get the mean of the pair of unused variables for each row as well. Is there a way to somehow amend your code to get mean(sample(x, 3)) plus the mean of whatever two variables weren't chosen from sample(x, 3)?

Comment: @CineyEveryday Updated the answer. This will return you two new columns.